# Bind scroll event to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently looking to add a scroll event to an image sequence only when the mouse is over the image.  I do not want the page to scroll but just to scroll through the images.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pictureCount = $('#container img').length;
  var scrollResolution = 50;


  animateImage();
});
function animateImage() {
    var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var imageIndex = Math.round(currentScrollPosition / scrollResolution);

    if (imageIndex >= pictureCount) {
        imageIndex = pictureCount - 1; // Select last image
    }

    $("#container img").hide();
    $("#container img").eq(imageIndex).show();
}

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    animateImage();
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <img src="frames/noindex_basset_02_img000.jpg" class="animated">
</div>
```

Comment: So you are essentially wanting the scroll up and scroll down as a prev/next interaction?

Comment: Than why you use `'scroll'` on `window`? jQuery `$()` can also accept a selector like your `"#container"` you know. But unable to help further without seeing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up this little example of how you could capture the `wheel` event on the container and swap things depending on a threshold and scroll direction.

```js
!function(){
  var totalVerticalDistanceScrolled = 0;
  //changable to configure how sensitive the scroll change is
  var scrollDistanceToChangeElements = 200;
  var $elementsToChange = $('.animated');
  
  //capture the wheel event when it is over the container
  $('#container').on('wheel', function(e){
    //sum up how much the user has scrolled.  scrolling up is negative
    totalVerticalDistanceScrolled += e.originalEvent.deltaY;
    
    //in the threshold has been met either up or down, swap elements
    if (Math.abs(totalVerticalDistanceScrolled) >= scrollDistanceToChangeElements) {
      var currentElementIndex = $elementsToChange.filter('.active').index();
      var nextElementIndex;
      
      //hide the currently shown element
      $elementsToChange.eq(currentElementIndex).removeClass('active');

      if (totalVerticalDistanceScrolled > 0) {
        //get the next element index, wrap back to the first element at the end
        nextElementIndex = (currentElementIndex + 1) % $elementsToChange.length;
      } else {
        //get the previous element index, wrap back to the last element at the end
        nextElementIndex = ( currentElementIndex || $elementsToChange.length ) - 1;
      }

      //show the next desired element
      $elementsToChange.eq(nextElementIndex).addClass('active');
      //clear out the total distance so the user can change direction if they want
      totalVerticalDistanceScrolled = 0;
    }
  });
}();
```

```css
.animated {
  display: none;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.animated.active { display: inline-block; }

.red { background-color: red; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }

#container {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="animated red active"></div>
  <div class="animated green"></div>
  <div class="animated blue"></div>
</div>
```